# webpack : live reload force chrome reload even on breakpoints

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic3, webpack-dev-server

My environement is Ionic, but the scope of this question relates more about webpack and the live reload functionality.

When using `ionic serve`
the livereload works as expected, my application refreshes in the browser everytime a source file changes.

Something that makes me waste time though, is everytime Chrome is stuck on a breakpoint (which happens very often as i use them a lot), the live reload won't work, so i must do the reload manually, or skip the breakpoints.

I understand it must be due to the fact that the script responsible for the reload is executed in the browser, so is locked by the breakpoint, and therefore unable to do its job.

So my question is : is there a different solution to make it so that a change in my file would force a reload of Chrome, no matter if it's stuck on a breakpoint or not. I guess the reload would have to come from a script that is executed in the console and not in the browser.

Thank in advance.